# Best way to create a formula for meter readings

Tags: design

I have to design a way to create, store, and use formulas to read values from meters (electricity, water, etc). Example:
Take 20% of meter 1, add to that 30% of meter 2 and subtract 100% of meter 3.
I have come up with the idea for user input, the user could select a meter from the list, and write next to it the value from -100% to +100%. But how can I store this created formula (example - "meter1ID+20%", "meter2ID+30%", "meter3ID-100%"), so that my program could later easily calculate values using this formula when having access to readings from these meters?
The first thing that comes to my mind, it to just store it as a string, but then reading the formula for the program would be hard.

How should I design this functionality?

Comment: This looks like a job for a spreadsheet. If you have something else in mind you’re going to have to let us in on it.

Comment: does your application have a database that you can use for this?

Comment: @marstato yes it does.

Comment: @candied_orange I have written "so that my program could later easily calculate values " - which means that I have a software that I am making, which needs this functionality. Not a spreadsheet.

Comment: @TK-421 have you tried storing meter id and the percental addition/subtraction in separate columns?

Comment: How arbitrary are your formulas?  Is it always summing percentages of meters?

Comment: @candied_orange Yes, always a sum of meters, either positive, or negative, that is why I have written "write next to it the value from -100% to +100%".

Comment: @marstato But how would I store this for three meters? Three different rows? Is it a good design, to separate this kind of formula between different rows of data?

Comment: Are the users who enter meter values the same users who set percentage values?

Comment: @candied_orange One user creates the formula. After that other users enter meter values each month, and the formula will calculate new values based on the entered meter values.

Comment: Are the number of meters fixed? Or does that vary?

Comment: You say “formulas” as if it’s plural. Does this mean you’ll have many formulas calculating at once or just one formula for each set of meter readings?

Comment: @candied_orange number of meters vary. It can be just one meter, or two, but probably no more than 5. I will have many formulas, made up of many meters. Same meter can be included in different formulas.

Comment: You would store a list of pairs where each pair has a meter ID and a percentage. Am I missing anything?

Comment: @user253751 yes, you are missing the fact, that I need multiple formulas made up of multiple meters, so just storing ID and percentage would not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your formula is always summing a percentages of a meter readings, then there are two obvious ways to store your formula's

1. If you have a relatively small, fixed, number of meters and the majority of them are used in each formula, you can just create a single table with a column for each meter and the percentage of that meter as the values. Non-selected meters would contribute 0% in that formula.
2. If the assumptions above don't hold, you can use two tables. One table (`formula`) contains a row for each formula and contains at least an id for the formula. The second table (`formula_components`) contains rows with the formula-id, meter-id and percentage contribution. Then you can check for each meter if it is contained in the formula_components table for formula X and what contribution it has in that formula.

Comment: Number of meters is probably somewhere around 100, and formula will be made up of 1 to 5 of these meters, and they will be new meters added in the future, so a fixed table with columns for each meter is not a good idea.

Looking at option 2 - Reading this formula would be downloading each row from formula_components which belong to this formula, then via meter-id and percentage value calculating the value and adding it to some variable. Yeah, that sounds good it doesn't depend on the number of meters and other scalability factors, and reading sounds simple enough to implement.